# GA4 not showing all data (eg countries)

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-4

We report our stats every week and for years have had visitors from about 140 countries each week.  This was reported fine in GA4 but now only the 40 top countries are being reported in our reports.  Our visitor numbers did not go down and the stats have not changed like this in UA.

This is also happening with web pages.  We have thousands of pages that get viewed each week but in GA4 it only shows the top 500 or so.  What is going on?

We did not change any settings and we are looking at the full reports.  Have even tried downloading to see if there’s additional data but there is none.  We’re worried that Google is thresholding the data but this is stuff we look at and use.

Edit: code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){window.dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-XXx');
</script>
```

Comment: please edit your question and include your code.   I need to see how you are requesting this information from the API

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo I made the edit, but it had previously shown us 140 countries and it went down to 40 without us editing the code or any settings

Comment: I don't think this question is programming related have you tried web apps Stack exchange?

Comment: Dear Lilly, I see you are still using the gtag code related to Universal Analytics, the gtm Id in GA4 does not start with UA. In case you add some photos from your analytics panel I may be able to help you better.

Comment: @ShilaMosammami yes, the UA and GA4 are linked so the data does go to GA4.  What types of screenshots would you need?

Comment: @Lilly as far as I know, there is no link between these two. you can only have them together since july 2023.  So you have to put the script related to GA4 in your website.

Comment: @ShilaMosammami yes you can have them synced by the UA code.  Else we wouldn't be getting any data to our GA4 at all and it would be an easy fix